# Cisco NAC: help with enabling FTP or moving update files

Tags: linux, unix, cisco, ftp, fedora

So this is a LINUX question, and a Cisco NAC question.

I'm trying to update our server from 4.1 to 4.7, and i need to move some tarball files to the NAC.  the NAC Appliance runs some strange stripped down version of Fedora Core 4

copying the upgrade:
The instructions say to FTP the file to the NAC appliance, however whenever i use WinSCP with root credentials, i get a notice informing me the connection was actively refused.

I can't for the life of me find any .conf files that sound like winners, so I don't know how to change the settings, however the ftp command does seem to work.

what exactly should I do here?

Comment: Let me get this straight before I attempt to answer you.
You are trying to put some upgrade file onto your NAS' harddisk so you can commence the upgrade of the NAS. Correct??? What server? 4.1 to 4.7? What? Sorry, it's unclear.

Comment: Yes, we are upgrading the NAS; we're going 4.1 to 4.6, and then 4.6 to 4.7 on a NAC appliance 3310

Comment: Is this a typo for Cisco NAS, or are you actually running Cisco's Network Access Protection (NAP)?  I'm trying to figure out if anyone in the world is actually running NAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinSCP be sure your file protocol is SFTP not plain old FTP.

I believe to go from 4.1 to 4.7.2 you should have burned the 4.7.1 ISO image. Then you can use the tag.gz or ISO method to go to 4.7.2 You should not need to copy any files to the servers. Be sure to carefully review the release notes of your target version to make sure you are following the correct upgrade path.

When in doubt contact Cicso TAC.